# Update JavaFX window from a java based object

Tags: java, javafx

I am in the process of learning JavaFX and I am looking for a tutorial about updating a JavaFX display with a java object.  For example, receive status updates @ 1hz from a server and display them on the fx window.  Is this possible?  If so, are there any tutorials?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my understanding that calling JavaFX from Java is not well supported at this time. However, here are two blog posts that at least touch on the subject:

- [How to Use JavaFX in Your Swing Application](http://blogs.oracle.com/javafx/entry/how_to_use_javafx_in)
- [Calling JavaFX From Java?](http://java.dzone.com/news/calling-javafx-from-java)

I think a more natural solution is to provide an access point in your Java code and set up JavaFX to periodically poll for new updates, i.e. JavaFX asks for new data rather than having Java tell it.